# CSS Viewport - Always have to zoom out a little

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport

I am using the following viewport in a web design....

```
<meta name="viewport" content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1'>
```

As far as I can tell this should open the site fully zoomed out, but when I visit on an iPad I always have to zoom out by a little bit.

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Do **not** disable zooming by using maximum scale - this is a terrible accessibility experience for users with poor eyesight. This isn't just those born with a disability, but loss of eyesight will eventually happen to most people (including both of us in all probability). It also is a poor user experience for any users who just want to zoom in, to see more detail in a picture for example. Can we see your CSS? Do you have your body or page container set at 100% width, and also margin/padding on the same element?

Answer (score 0):

`width=device-width` tells all, it sets the width to the device width (ipad) so roughly 1024 (landscape), so your page is wider than that if you have to zoom out

Comment: Is there a way I can tell it to just zoom to fit the devices width so I don't need to zoom out any whatever device it is on?

Comment: You can just pass in a width instead of device width - but I don't know how wide your site is so can't give you a number

Comment: The site is 1070pixels wide

Comment: then set it `width=1070`

Comment: @fightstarr20 If you want your site to respond to the width of the user's device then you need to declare widths in percentages. See http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design/, http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/, http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design - if you don't want it to respond then remove the meta viewport tag, and it will be zoomed out by default on most tablets (including the iPad I believe).

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css

```
@media screen and (max-width:yourdevice-px) {
    @-ms-viewport{
        width:required-px;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should explain how adding your code solves the issue